# ElectronJS - Vite - React / Route problem on production

Tags: reactjs, windows, electron, vite

I created an app with React Vite and Electron, in the project I am using Firebase and I created an AuthProvider to be able to keep the routes inaccessible at the time of not having the authenticated session. When I do the dmg for macOS it works correctly, but at the time of making the .exe for Windows, the program is installed but when I open the program I do not see anything, or good does not show the component, only the Footer, and the NotFoundPage Component

My **main.jsx**

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.jsx'
import { AuthProvider } from './services/AuthContext.jsx';
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <AuthProvider>
            <App />
        </AuthProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

My **App.jsx**

```
function App() {
    return (
        <AuthProvider>
            <Router>
                <div className="flex h-screen p-0 bg-white">
                    <NavBar/>
                    <div className="flex-1 flex items-center justify-center">
                        <Routes>
                            <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>}/>

                            <Route path="/" element={<PrivateRoute/>}>
                                <Route index element={<Inicio/>}/>

                                <Route path="/examenes" element={<ExamenesPage/>}/>
                          
                                <Route path="/examenes/buscar-examen" element={<BuscarExamen/>}/>

                                <Route path="*" element={<NotFoundPage/>}/>
                            </Route>
                        </Routes>
                    </div>
                    <Footer/>
                </div>
            </Router>
        </AuthProvider>
    );
}
```

my **electron.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');

const isDev = process.env.IS_DEV == "true" ? true : false;

function createWindow() {
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1200,
        height: 800,
        autoHideMenuBar: true,
        resizable: true,
        frame: true,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false
        },
        icon: path.join(__dirname, "../assets/icons/logo.icns")
    });

    mainWindow.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler((edata) => {
        shell.openExternal(edata.url);
        return { action: "deny" };
    });

    mainWindow.loadURL(
        isDev
            ? 'http://localhost:3000/'
            : `file://${path.join(__dirname, '../dist/index.html')}`
    );

    mainWindow.setMinimumSize(1200, 800);
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow()
    app.on('activate', function () {
        if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
    })
});

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});
```

my **package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "system",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "electron/electron.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc --noEmit && vite build",
    "serve": "vite preview",
    "electron": "wait-on tcp:3000 && cross-env IS_DEV=true electron .",
    "electron:pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "electron:dev": "concurrently -k \"cross-env BROWSER=none npm run dev\" \"npm run electron\"",
    "electron:builder": "electron-builder",
    "build:for:electron": "cross-env ELECTRON=true vite build",
    "app:build": "npm run build:for:electron && npm run electron:builder"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^8.2.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "firebase": "^10.3.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.15.0",
    "wait-on": "^7.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.15",
    "electron": "^26.3.0",
    "electron-builder": "^24.6.4",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.29",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3",
    "vite": "^4.4.5"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.holairs.package",
    "productName": "System Lab",
    "copyright": "Copyright © 2023",
    "mac": {
      "category": "public.app-category.utilities",
      "icon": "../src/assets/icons/logo.icns"
    },
    "win": {
      "icon": "../src/assets/micro.png"
    },
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": false,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true
    },
    "files": [
      "dist/**/*",
      "electron/**/*"
    ],
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "assets",
      "output": "dist_electron"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to create the `_directories` file mentioned in another discussion ([Routes not working properly in React using Vite (ON BUILD)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75375772/routes-not-working-properly-in-react-using-vite-on-build#:%7E:text=Here%27s%20what%20needs%20to%20be%20done.%201%20-,build%20command%20and%20deploy%20it%20on%20the%20netlify.)), but it didn't work. I also tried to create the .exe from windows but it keeps giving me the same error